# Snowflake [History page] - how to see certain values in SQL statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

when I go to the history page, I see a list of executed queries, but when I check a particular one, I can't see its arguments just a question marks instead of a values. Is it possible to see these values or are they secret for security reasons?

```
SELECT * FROM table(information_schema.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_WAREHOUSE(WAREHOUSE_NAME => concat('', ?, ''), RESULT_LIMIT => ?)) WHERE QUERY_ID IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: Was this query run by you? Maybe someone worked with  parameters in his query and his substitution failed. And that’s what you see know... quotation marks instead of correct values...

Comment: This can also happen if it's a query generated by the system outside a user generated query, see [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html#overview-of-features) : Use the Include client-generated statements checkbox to show or hide SQL statements run by web interface sessions outside of SQL worksheets. For example, whenever a user navigates to the Warehouses Warehouses tab, Snowflake executes a SHOW WAREHOUSES statement in the background. Clear the Include client-generated statements checkbox to hide this “noise” in the list of displayed queries.